# Formset populated by wrong data - Django 1.8

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Basic problem: I have a list of products, and when I go to edit a single product, the image upload formset is populated with all images in the folder, but it should only be populated by related images (see left hand side of  picture below).

When I try to make any changes - to the product or to the images - it is unsuccessful, and the input boxes which were populated by unrelated images now display 'this field is required' (see right hand side of picture below)

[image: django formset populated with wrong data]

Obviously, I need to successfully edit the product object, and I want this page to be populated only by images related to that product.

The View

```
def EditProduct(request, pk):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Product, id=pk)
    ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(ProductImage,
                                        form=ImageForm, extra=4)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_form = AddEditProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)
        formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,
                        queryset=ProductImage.objects.none())

        if product_form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():

            product = product_form.save()

            images = formset.save(commit=False)
            for image in images:
                image.product = product
                image.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/product/')

        else:
            print (product_form.errors, formset.errors)

    else:
        product_form = AddEditProductForm(instance=instance)
        formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=ProductImage.objects.all()) # possible wrong queryset

    return render(request, 'product/edit.html',
                  {'product_form': product_form, 'formset': formset},
                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

So this code is somehow returning ALL of my uploaded images - including unrelated images - to the editing form for a single product - how do I make it so only those images which are related to the instance are displayed in the form?

On a related note - how do you access an individual image in the formset - for example if i wanted to remove one, what kind of modifications am I looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your model.

`formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=ProductImage.objects.all()) # possible wrong queryset`

This is indeed the wrong queryset. You should do something like:

`queryset=ProductImage.objects.filter(product_id = pk)`

if you gave the product_image field a `related_name` than you could do

`queryset=instance.related_product_images`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: Your queryset does work, I had assumed it wouldn't return multiple images, but it does, thanks. However, I still cannot edit the instance - it reverts to 'this field is required'.